# What approaches can I take to find out my blood type and Rhesus factor?

Tags: blood-tests, blood-type

I need to find out my blood type and Rhesus factor.

However, there is no medical necessity for this - it's just to know myself.

(as such, I'm aware that medical insurance would likely not cover the costs).

What are the realistic (and hopefully cost effective) approaches I can take to find out this info?

E.g., should I just request such a test to be done at my General Practicioner? (and if so how much would the tests likely cost as far as order of magnitude)?

Should I ask at some fertility clinic since they often care about Rh factor? Would they agree to test a random walk-in male, who isn't a registered sperm donor or patient with them?

Should I just go to Quest or Labcorp office?

My three main parameters to evaluate the proposed solutions are:

1. Convenience for an New York City, USA resident. The answer shouldn't propose showing up at some free clinic in California :)
2. Reliability of results. The answer shouldn't be "Do this, but chances are they will refuse to help you because you don't fit their criteria".
3. Out of pocket costs. I'm willing to shell out a reasonable ($100?) amount for this, but not $300.

Comment: You can order lab tests online so do a web search. As I recall there are a couple of states that don't allow you to order your own tests but I don't recall which they are. Blood typing should be pretty cheap.

Answer (score 4):

**Donate blood.** Blood donation is free.

If you are a healthy individual who is eligible to donate blood, for example to the American Red Cross, they will need to test your blood for basic type (ABO and Rh), various antibodies, etc. You will not get this information immediately when you donate, but you can access it later on request, or you may be mailed a card that contains this information to expedite future donation (and they may push you a bit harder to donate if you have a particularly in-demand blood type).

Some information from the Red Cross:

[Blood testing](https://www.redcrossblood.org/biomedical-services/blood-diagnostic-testing/blood-testing.html)

[Blood donor app](https://www.redcrossblood.org/blood-donor-app.html)

If you are not in an area where the Red Cross is a common collector of donated blood, you can look up local providers.